# Expect output write to a file

Tags: bash, expect

I am trying to login to a remote device and write it`s output to a file. I came up with this code. But in rez.txt file i get line "(buffer)"

My code is very basic - from manual, i do not know what is wrong:

```
/usr/bin/expect << SSHLOGIN

spawn ssh -l $user $host

set timeout 100

expect {
"assword: " {
        send "$password\r"
        }
}
expect {
">" {
        send "?\r"
        }
}
expect {
"?" {
        puts [open rez.txt w] $expect_out(buffer)
        }
}

expect {
">" {
        send "exit\r"
        }
}
SSHLOGIN
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are calling Expect in a bash script.

The `$expect_out` part of `$expect_out(buffer)` is being substituted by the shell. Since `$expect_out` is not set to anything, the Expect program is actually doing this:

```
puts [open rez.txt w] (buffer)
```

So it's basically putting the word `(buffer)`.

To fix this, you need to escape `$expect_out` so that it is not expanded by the shell and passed correctly to Expect, like this:

```
puts [open rez.txt w] \$expect_out(buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

expect's default matching mode is ["glob"](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M39) and <kbd>?</kbd> is a special glob character. After you send "?", when expect sees a single character, your output file is written.

If you're expecting a literal <kbd>?</kbd>, then you want to use **exact** matching:

```
expect -ex "?" {
    puts [open rez.txt w] $expect_out(buffer)
}
```

Comment: I have tried to change command, for example ifconfig but output to a file is still "(buffer)". Maybe the best solution would be to write all expect output to a file and remove first lines...